# Случайная ссылка при клике

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Мне необходимо, чтобы каждый раз при клике по ссылке выполнялась функция и ссылка обновлялась. Пробовал по всякому, но ссылка обновляется только после перезагрузки страницы.

```js
function qclick() {
    var a = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
    var arr = ["http://google.com", "http://yandex.ru", "http://stackoverflow.com", "http://mail.ru", "http://youtube.com"];
return(arr[a]);
}
document.write ("<font color='Red'><b>Тут появляется случайная ссылка: </font> <a href= "+qclick()+" target='_blank'  onclick="+qclick()+">Случайная ссылка</a></b>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас у вас функция в `onclick` используется неверно.

Во-первых, она выполняется один раз при загрузке страницы, а не при каждом клике. Чтобы она выполнялась каждый раз - не нужно её выносить за пределы строки. Именно имя функции должно быть значением атрибута `onlick`, а не её результат.

Во-вторых, у вас сейчас функция `qclick` возвращает адрес. Если при вызове в `href` это оправдано, то в `onclick` вы присваиваете вместо обработчика - ссылку. Вам нужно в onclick передавать функцию, которая будет присваивать атрибуту `href` новое значение.

Рабочий пример на JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qvjt94z7/

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать ф-ю, которая будет менять ссылке название и `href`.

Чтобы юзер себя чувствовал комфортно, лучше устанавливать ссылку не по клику, *мгновенно* перед переходом, а *заранее*: юзер сможет увидеть, куда ведёт ссылка, прежде, чем кликать. Считаю это правильным.

План: ставим ссылке случайно один из url'ов, и ждём клика. При клике, уже открыв новое окно с url'ом, ставим новый url в ссылку.

```
var links = ["http://google.com", "http://yandex.ru", "http://stackoverflow.com", "http://mail.ru", "http://youtube.com"],
  tag;

// эта сработает сразу по клику, _перед_ переходом по ссылке,
// поэтому ставим нулевую задержку, чтобы сначала был переход
// по текущей ссылке, а уже после она поменялась на новую
function delayMe() {
  window.setTimeout( changeLink, 0);
  return true;
}

// смена ссылки на новую случайную
// TODO: проверять, что новая ссылка не совпала со старой
function changeLink() {
  var url = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
  tag.href = url;
  tag.innerHTML = url;
}

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<span class="e-label">Тут появляется случайная ссылка:</span> <a href="#" target="_blank" id="e-link">Случайная ссылка</a>';

tag = document.getElementById('e-link'); // нашли один раз, и запомнили
changeLink(); // установить какую-то ссылку в самом начале

tag.addEventListener('click', delayMe);  // слушаем события клика
```

Тут в песочнице ссылки не срабатывают, поэтому [вот фиддл](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/a7qvykvd/2/).

Comment: а разве `setTimeout` заполнит параметр `e`?

Comment: @Grundy не заполнит. Косяк почищен, спасибо!